# Ubi-partman fails with exit code 141 when installing via hard disk

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, unetbootin

I'm currently running Windows 10, and am attempting to install Kubuntu 19.10 via [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io)'s hard disk install of the ISO. The booting and installation continues fine up until disk setup, where it notifies me that ubi-partman fails with exit code 141. I can only assume this has something the do with the fact I'm booting from the hard drive, but I was wondering if there was any way to fix this.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We bumped into the same situation with the exit code 141. We use the usb and select the second option to boot. After reboot, we can select the first option and can install the image without the exit code 141.